# CSRF token is invalid after changing Host

Tags: php, symfony, session, csrf

we had a Symfony2 project and for some reason we've changed the Host, after changing to a host with Plesk Panel,  we are facing with `The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.`, I tried to figure out why? then provide a simple  Twig form with following codes :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    {# ... #}

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>ADD Item to Crawling List</h2>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and it rendered correctly

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>ADD Item to Crawling List</h2>
    <form name="form" method="post">
    <div id="form"><div><label for="form_post_id" class="required">Instagram Post Id</label><input type="text" id="form_post_id" name="form[post_id]" required="required" /></div><div><button type="submit" id="form_save" name="form[save]">Fetch Comments</button></div><input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="j9YWKseFdkU4Z_Yc5nuwm72SKD4dT06gJpARLqPID6I" /><button type="submit" id="form_save" name="form[save]">Fetch Comments</button></div>    
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also tried to add `{{ form_rest(form) }}` but Not any achievement and the result is the same.

Another note is we didn't override session config handler in `config`.yml` and it's

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
```

any solution or idea help us to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: try adding a hidden `input` to your `form` and place the `CSRF_token` in that input field.

Comment: @Deathstorm token is exist there, please look carefully,

Comment: Didn't see the token at first, sorry

Comment: Since you're using method="post", where is the submit button?

Comment: @Deathstorm it's there , it may because I add four space here it getting hidden in stackoverflow render system.

Comment: @Deathstorm I think the issue is not related to formapi and form, it might relates to session save or environmental variables and configuration , everything was working on previous host.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146035/discussion-between-deathstorm-and-zhilevan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add:

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Just before the form_end, this adds the CSRF token in a hidden input in your form.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't saw that, sorry ! I've no other ideas :/

Comment: it was not related to Symfony, after some changes on VPS  worked.